# How to manipulate an element only if two buttons have been clicked

Tags: javascript

I want to change the background-color of my box1 to red only if both buttons have been clicked.

HTML:

```
<button id="button1">klick me</button>
<button id="button2">klick me</button>
<div class="box1"></div>
```

Css:

```
.box1 {
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
background-color: blue;
}
.id2 {
background-color: red;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function changeColor (){
let button1 = document.querySelector('#button1');
let button2 = document.querySelector('#button2');
let box1 = document.querySelector('.box1');

if(this.id === 'button1'){
box1.classList.toggle('id2');
}     
}

button1.addEventListener('click', changeColor);
button2.addEventListener('click', changeColor);
```

The previous code works as expected. If button1 got clicked the color of box1 changes to red.

So i tried this following if statement to achieve that the color only get changed if both buttons have been clicked:

```
if(this.id === 'button1' && this.id === 'button2' ){
box1.classList.toggle('id2');
}
```

But unfortunately it's not working. What am i missing?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's like writing `var value = prompt(); if (value === 'foo' && value === 'bar') { console.log('Equal to two different values at the same time!!!'); }`

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this [using promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises):

```js
function once (handler) {
  return function one ({ type }) {
    this.removeEventListener(type, one)
    return handler.apply(this, arguments)
  }
}

function when (type, selector) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    document.querySelector(selector).addEventListener(type, once(resolve))
  })
}

Promise.all([
  when('click', '#button1'),
  when('click', '#button2')
]).then(function () {
  document.querySelector('.box1').classList.toggle('id2')
})
```

```css
.box1 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.id2 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<button id="button1">click me</button>
<button id="button2">click me</button>
<div class="box1"></div>
```

You can extend this to toggle repeatedly if you put the promise chain into an [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and use a `while` loop:

```js
function once (handler) {
  return function one ({ type }) {
    this.removeEventListener(type, one)
    return handler.apply(this, arguments)
  }
}

function when (type, selector) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    document.querySelector(selector).addEventListener(type, once(resolve))
  })
}

async function toggler () {
  const box = document.querySelector('.box1')

  while (true) {
    await Promise.all([
      when('click', '#button1'),
      when('click', '#button2')
    ])

    box.classList.toggle('id2')
  }
}

toggler()
```

```css
.box1 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.id2 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<button id="button1">click me</button>
<button id="button2">click me</button>
<div class="box1"></div>
```

Comment: Beautiful solution, I wasn't aware that promises could help here. Very elegant!

Answer (score 1):

try this

Javascript:

```
var clicks = {
  button1: false,
  button2: false
}

var box1 = document.querySelector('.box1');
var button1 = document.querySelector('#button1');
var button2 = document.querySelector('#button2');

function clicked(e){
  var btn = this.id;
  clicks[btn] = true;

  if(clicks.button1 && clicks.button2){
    //change color
    box1.classList.toggle('id2');

    // reset object to initial state (if needed)
    clicks = {
      button1: false,
      button2: false
    }
  }
}

button1.addEventListener('click', clicked);
button2.addEventListener('click', clicked);
```

Edit: added event listeners on buttons instead of `onclick`

Comment: I wouldn't advise using inline event listeners.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

Whenever a button is clicked, if it hasn't been clicked before, add it to the list `clickedButtons[]`.

When a button is added, check if both buttons are in the list, and if so, toggle the css class and empty the list, so the whole thing can start over. The next time both buttons have been clicked the color is going to revert to the initial color.

```js
const clickedButtons = [];
[b1, b2].forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (clickedButtons.includes(e.target)) return; // button was clicked before
  clickedButtons.push(e.target);
  if ([b1, b2].every(b => clickedButtons.includes(b))) {
    box1.classList.toggle('red');
    clickedButtons.length = 0; // empty the list so we can start over
  }
}))
```

```css
#box1 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#box1.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<button id="b1" type="button">klick me</button>
<button id="b2" type="button">klick me</button>
<div id="box1"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click a button, the `this` inside its click event listener (`changeColor`) will be the context of the button you just clicked, as such the ID will only be one or the other and never both.

You will want to have some kind of state object to keep track of both buttons, and when both are clicked, then perform the change:

```
let state = {
    button1Clicked: false,
    button2Clicked: false
};

let button1 = document.querySelector('#button1');
let button2 = document.querySelector('#button2');
let box1 = document.querySelector('.box1');

function changeColor () {
    this.id === 'button1'
        ? state.button1Clicked = true
        : state.button2Clicked = true;

    if (state.button1Clicked && state.button2Clicked) {
        box1.classList.toggle('id2');
    }
}

button1.addEventListener('click', changeColor);
button2.addEventListener('click', changeColor);
```